# ADO.NET : new transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

I'm trying to use Transaction while updating multiple tables at once, I'm using ADO.net and stored procedures with SQL server 2019 database.
I'm keeping get this Error :

`new transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session`

The code I'm using is :

```
try
        {
            if (GV.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            DB_conn.BeginTransaction();

            DB_conn.Query2("update_invoice_kitchen");
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kitchen", 1);
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", INVOICEID);
            DB_conn._cmd.Transaction = DB_conn._sqlTransaction;
            DB_conn.QueryNonEx();

            DB_conn.Query2("update_sales_history_status");
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "جديد");
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_id", INVOICEID);
            DB_conn._cmd.Transaction = DB_conn._sqlTransaction;
            DB_conn.QueryNonEx();

            DB_conn.Query2("update_invoice_status");
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "معلق");
            DB_conn._cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", INVOICEID);
            DB_conn._cmd.Transaction = DB_conn._sqlTransaction;
            DB_conn.QueryNonEx();

            DB_conn._sqlTransaction.Commit();

            Create_invoice();

            MessageBox.Show("1");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("2");
            if (DB_conn._sqlTransaction != null)
            {
                DB_conn._sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

and here is the Database class :

```
class DB_connection
{
    public readonly SqlConnection _con;
    public SqlCommand _cmd;
    public SqlDataAdapter _da;
    public DataTable _dt;
    public DataSet _ds;
    public SqlDataReader _dr;
    public SqlTransaction _sqlTransaction;

    readonly string ConnectionString = "Server=" + Properties.Settings.Default.server + ";Database=" + Properties.Settings.Default.database + ";User Id=" + Properties.Settings.Default.user + ";Password=" + Properties.Settings.Default.password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    //readonly string ConnectionString = "Server = DESKTOP-1OO2GKV; Database=Transfer_Manager; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    public DB_connection()
    {
        _con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            _con.Open();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            //Settings_form frm = new Settings_form();
            //frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public void Query2(string Storedproc)
    {
        _cmd = new SqlCommand(Storedproc, _con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
    }

    public void Query(string queryText)
    {
        _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, _con);
    }
    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _dt = new DataTable();
        _da.Fill(_dt);
        return _dt;
    }
    public DataSet QueryEx_DS()
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _ds = new DataSet();
        _da.Fill(_ds);

        return _ds;
    }
    public DataSet QueryEx_paging2(int _Start, int _MaxObj, string Table)
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _ds = new DataSet();
        //_dt = new DataTable();
        _da.Fill(_ds, _Start, _MaxObj, Table);

        return _ds;
    }
    public void QueryNonEx()
    {
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    public void QueryExScalar()
    {
        _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    public SqlTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        _sqlTransaction = _con.BeginTransaction();
        return _sqlTransaction;
    }
}
```

I'm using the same code and the same way in another project but without stored procedures and it's working fine.

Comment: Your code seems OK. So are there, by any chance, `other threads` possibly `running in the session`?

Comment: @JakubFojtik , Yes, it seems there is something in the current form cause this problem, I tried to use transaction in a different form and its work fine.
how can I find the thread that causes this problem ??